# angularjs JSONP Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, request, jsonp

I have a problem with jsonp request. I am using AngularJS 1.6 and I do a jsonp request and I get error in response.
Here is my code

```
this.changePhoto = function(){

        var getPhoto = function(){
            var params = {
                callback: "JSON_CALLBACK",
            };
            $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(context.upload_url)
            return $http.jsonp(context.upload_url, {
                params: params
            });
        }

        getPhoto().then(function(response){
           //Here video response
           console.log(response);
        });

    }
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And this is the response after request:

```
{"server":841237,"photo":"[]","hash":"09d049a834648f1f6dabab78327b449f"}
```

Comment: That is not jsonp. Are you sure the api serves jsonp? Not all do

Comment: Yes I am sure. I'm trying to upload photo through VK(vkontakte) API

Comment: That doesn't make sense...can't do an upload using jsonp request. It is a script request that can not contain body content. Suggest you read up on how `JSONP` works

Comment: Ok, but I get response from server, but I can't parse it, and I can not use it.

Comment: Try changing to `$http.get()`

Comment: In this case I get CORS issue.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Well if api doesn't enable CORS or serve jsonp then you need to use a proxy